# How to implement database in PhoneGap App ?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm new to this, and I am trying to build an app to be deployed with PhoneGap, to both Android and iOS. 
I am wondering how to link to a database which will store timetable data.

My question is how to include the database so it can be packaged with PhoneGap.

I have looked at the PhoneGap docs, and they don't really make sense to me as to how to set up/create the database

---

Update:
This website shows some info on local storage, but when i put it in, hangs on the loading image.

Any further ideas?

http://www.aquim.com/web-article-237.html

Comment: Did you find where we can see our data in db for android

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please refer below link for  simple operation with Sq-lite.and also you can get basic idea of Storage API from above [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage).

Simple operation with Sq-lite :
http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/10/20/Example-of-PhoneGaps-Database-Support

**Edited on 8th MAY 2013 and fixed 19th January 2016**

Basic operation with DB :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-x.x.x.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
// Wait for Cordova to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

// Populate the database 
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}

// Transaction error callback
function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: " + err);
}

// Transaction success callback
function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
}
</script>
```

[refrence](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)

You can check Data base in File explorer

In ADT bundle 
Window>>show view>> File Explorer

Comment: I have tried, but when I built the application in PhoneGap, and deployed it to an Android device, none of the database worked, I have tried [link](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-app-using-the-phonegap-database-api/) as well as the ones above, with the same result. Any html/css works fine.

Comment: please refer Basic operation with DB.

Comment: I am now more comfortable with SQL, so it now looks like it will work, will implement it soon. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to find where we can see our data in db for android

Comment: Page is not opening now please give other like

Comment: The sample code has an error in the errorCB parameters. A transaction error or success callback does NOT get a transaction parameter. Please remove the "tx" parameter from the errorCB function. I already made an edit to fix this problem and it was apparently ignored by the "peer review" cycle.

Comment: I also wish that I can remove my upvote on the answer since it has an error and my edit was ignored during the "peer review" cycle.

Comment: @MSTdev the program no matter whether you remove tx from the errorCB parameters or not. The questions to ask are: (1) should the tx parameter be there and (2) how do we show the actual error? My answers are (1) the tx parameter should *not* be there and (2) both remove the tx parameter and use JSON.stringify(err) when you log or otherwise display the error.

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap has a storage api that you should use instead of using HTML5 local storage directly. On both Android and iOS, it will use the native implementation.

see http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: I have tried that, but as with the comment above, I get no database result.

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific - please show your code and tell us exactly what the behavior / result is.

Comment: Is it deprecated in the latest version? I couldn't find similar documentation in the latest http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage . Instead, it suggests to use HTML 5 based storage

Answer (score 0):

Careful because maxSize of database in Android Gingerbread 2.3.3 emulator must be 65535.

With this OS 200000 maxSize  it could give an error.

200000 maxSize works for newer OS.