# Unable to load the database in android through phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to create and insert into database using phonegap

I got the `cordova 2.4 jar` file from [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcordova240jar.htm)

and I tried this code but unable to read the database.

Where I can see the database in android I tried in emulatior i.e. on `mnt--> Sd` card and `data--> Data--> project db`.

No database found in these paths.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Storage Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    function populateDB(tx) {
         tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SAMPLE');
         tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SAMPLE (id unique, data)');
         tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First")');
         tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second")');
    }

    function errorCB(tx, err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
    }

    function successCB() {
        alert("success!");
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Database</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you can find your answer in this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369532/how-to-implement-database-in-phonegap-app

Comment: @sarabu Why are using cordova 2.4? You can use the latest cordova 3.5 by downloading it from http://cordova.apache.org/. Also you need to put alert or console.log statements in order for you to debug the code. You need to tell us exactly what error you are getting so that we can help you. Making a general statement that it is not working will not help. And most of them will ignore your question.

Comment: @frank its just taking me this [link](https://www.apache.org/dist/cordova/) what to do... I mean its not showing any download option `3.5` is not visible here

Comment: @sarabu check this [link](http://cordova.apache.org/). Anyway I would suggest to install cordova/phonegap using node.js. Please search the web there are number of links available for installing cordova/phonegap using node.js

Comment: @frank I got the jar and js files but I have a new doubt: Is it possible to find where we can see our data in db for android

Comment: I do not have the info on the location of the DB. You can search on the stackoverflow for your query.

Comment: yes you can see your data in database.

Comment: See my answer below. If you have any doubt, feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 0):

> For viewing the table details, Eclipse has a plugin. Download it from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91846918/sqlite%20manager/com.questoid.sqlitemanager_1.0.0.jar.
>
> Now put the jar file in the folder eclipse/dropins/. You can find this folder where you have installed eclipse.
>
> Right click on your project. Choose 'Java Build path' then Click on 'Libraries' tab > Add External JARs > Choose Your Path to the SQLite JAR File! Add it.
>
> Restart the eclipse and now you can see the SQLite Manager plugin on the top right of the File Explorer window. (that blue color icon)

[image]

> Click on (database name), then click on “open file in SQLite Manager...”.

[image]

> Here, click on “Questoid SQLite Manager” tab and you can see your table in “Database Structure” tab.

[image]

> •  Then, click on “Browse Data” tab to view your table data.